# Merge two excel sheets the imported cells to match with each cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an inventory list which has contains 1000 product with zero pictures, and a sheet which have 300 links of the product pictures in excel, I'm looking for a way to combine the two sheets, so that each product will match with its picture link.

NOTE:
1. I have tried using Kutools add-in to import pictures matching to a cell value, which works perfectly, but Shopify wants only image links, not the image itself.
2. I then tried Ablebits add-in to compare the two sheets so that I can delete the cells that don't match, that works too, but I can't get the links column to match the names column.
3. Some of the links in the picture sheet contains partial, or full name of a product
4.The product sheet has a column with the names of the products
I'm using Excel 2016.
5. I have Kutool Add-ins, Ablebit Tools Add-ins and Ablebit Data Add-ins installed.

The First sheet "Product list" is the sheet that contains the list of the products [Screenshot of the product list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOWeh.png), The second sheet "Links of Product Images" contains the links of the images [Screenshot of the Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbuf3.jpg), The last sheet is an example of how I want it to be [Screenshot of my desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgqm9.png), Each image link matches to the product.

How can I achieve this please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a column in Product List sheet that contains the same values found in File Name in Links of Product Images sheet? You could use a Vlookup on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `sanitized name` column in `Product List` sheet has matches in `File Name` column in `Links of Product Images` sheet you can use a VLookup to get the URL. This also assumes that there are is **not** the same sanitized name for multiple products that have different URLs. It is easy enough to change formula if there is a lookup column that provides unique matches available. Hard to tell with screenshots provided.

In `Product List` sheet enter the following formula in column K and drag down for as many rows as required:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'Links of Product Images'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image: Image of formula]

You may need to amend the column lookups if the match is found using different columns.

Comment: Works like  charm, thank you thank you thank you. You just got me dancing here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub sa()
Sheet3.Range("A:B").Clear
Sheet1.Select 'PRODUCTLIST
Sheet1.Range("C:C").Copy
Sheet3.Select 'FINAL RESULT
Sheet3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                For Each PRng In Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            For Each RRng In Sheet2.Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
             If RRng = PRng Then
                RRng.Cells(1, 2).Copy
                Sheet3.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
           Next
           Next
End Sub
```

Please Inform if it is Useful .. Thank You..

Comment: Thank you @Thoppil, your code works great, it copies the links and place them in column B, but it does not align with the product name. I had to tweak your code a little by changing the ("C:C") to ("B:B"), because B contains the product name while C its just Sanitized name which some products don't have. So how can I sort the Column B which contains the link to match column A products name? each link should go to its product row